# Formatting on save moves import statment in VS-Code

Tags: python, flask, visual-studio-code, formatting

I am learning flask and building a app based on [Corey Schafer's Youtube tutorials](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL-osiE80TeTs4UjLw5MM6OjgkjFeUxCYH).
I'm using VS-Code as my editor of choice.

In tutorial 5 he splits his app into a package structure and when I do it I run into a problem. In my settings I enabled the `"editor.formatOnSave": true` and the formatter I use is autopep8.
Now when I move one of my import statements from the top to the bottom of my file and save, [the formatter moves it back to the top](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UoDOi.gif). I'm guessing its because of 'E402 - Fix module level import not at top of file'?

I tried to ignore it with the `"python.formatting.autopep8Args": [--ignore=E402]` but that did  nothing. Maybe here you can only turn of lynting errors and E402 is only a lynting error and its not relevant for the formatting?

I hope you can help me disable or fix it.

Cheers

Comment: I don't know `autopep8` well, but that example is mis-formatted as you're missing quotes around the argument: `"python.formatting.autopep8Args": ["--ignore=E402"]`.

Comment: For future readers this might help : https://stackoverflow.com/a/54016555/5753035.

Comment: @BrettCannon reading the link from Pramesh, you can even improve the right side of the setting: the arguments for the formatter should be passed as separate list items in quotes like ["--ignore","E402"] rather than [--ignore=E402]

Comment: @Timo they are equivalent, so you can choose whichever format you prefer as it makes no difference to autopep8.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Brett Cannon comment:**

> I don't know autopep8 well, but that example is mis-formatted as you're missing quotes around the argument: `"python.formatting.autopep8Args": ["--ignore=E402"]`

@BrettCannon terrific! That fixed it. Tried so long to fix it that i forgot those quotes and didnt see that they were missing.