# Disable python import sorting in VSCode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, format

I am trying to disable vscode from formatting my python imports when I save my file. I have some code that must run in between various imports so order is important, but every time I save it just shoves the imports to the top.

I tried putting

```
"editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
    "source.organizeImports": false
},
```

in my user settings but that doesn't fix it.

Thanks!

EDIT- I would like to keep formatting on save on except for the imports

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Formatting on save moves import statment in VS-Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53579109/formatting-on-save-moves-import-statment-in-vs-code)

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Check for the below setting in vscode settings, if it's true then set it to false for completely disabling formatting on save, like so :

```
 "editor.formatOnSave": false
```

**for formatting and to ignore imports not being at top itself**, first make the above setting **true** and add to your user settings and try adding this setting to your user settings, if you're using the default formatter for python, that is autopep8 :

```
"python.formatting.autopep8Args": ["--ignore","E402"]
```

where **E402 represents "module level import not at top of file"**

Note that this would only work if you are using the default formatter/linter. If you are using some other linter then i suggest you look up their documentation to see how it's done. Like most commonly one could make use of global config file, say $HOME/.config/.pycodestyle, and add necessary settings there, like :

```
[pycodestyle]
ignore = E402
```

**EDIT : the arguments for the formatter should be passed as separate list items in quotes like ["--ignore","E402"] rather than [--ignore=E402]**

Comment: That looks promising! I am using the default formatter, but "python.formatting.autopep8Args": [--ignore=E402]  gives an error. It says Value Expected jsonc 516. Any ideas?

Comment: not sure but can you try this : 
 ```"python.formatting.autopep8Args": ["--ignore","E402"]```. Like put the args as seperate list items inside quotes

Comment: Relevant VS Code docs on Python-specific formatter settings: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/editing#_formatting

Comment: strangely, but as soon as I add this argument ["--ignore","E402"], the formatting is entirely disabled, and the code is not formatted any longer...

Comment: @DarkTemplar I'd probably check the project specific or global config for the particular formatter that you are using, which might be disabling certain format features.

Comment: `"python.formatting.autopep8Args": ["--ignore","E402"]` is about to get deprecated