# How to turn off Sort Imports for a selection of files, glob or similar in VS Code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am trying to Mock an import in python for a test. My code looks something like this.

```
"""Python file description."""

import sys
import pytest

import datetime as dt

from unittest.mock import Mock

sys.modules['module_A'] = Mock()

from module_to_test import function_to_test
```

where I need to mock `module_A` as a dependency for `module_to_test`.

On save, VSCode auto-orders this alphabetically, and as a result creates the Mock after it tries to import from the module with the dependency.

**How do I prevent the Sort Imports from ordering a subset of files? This could be through a list of files, a glob, regex or similar?**

Glob pattern of the test file `./tests/test_*.py.`

---

**Update** - Partial solution posted below.

Comment: So what's a higher priority problem here, mocking module or un-sorting imports? Suggested reading: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem, wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem

Comment: @0xc0de my priority is to get my tests running so that I can deploy my script ASAP. Time taken to add on line to `settings.json` - 2 minutes. Time taken to read, understand and refactor my *tests* - lots of minutes.

Comment: @0xc0de that isn't to say I won't eventually, or that it isn't the right thing to do as per pep8.

Comment: Those lots of minutes will help you get your pep8 compliant work done quickly in future too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, you can't turn off import sorting an a per-module level through a VS Code-specific setting (it's either on or off). It would need to be supported by isort itself somehow.

Comment: @cmuk's `# isort: skip` method works for me

Answer (score 17):

If like mine your VSCode config is using isort (not autopep8) to do the import sorting, then you can override it on a selective basis like this:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
from . import views  # isort:skip
```

i.e. Add the `# isort:skip` comment to the import you don't want to jump to the top of the file.

Source: https://github.com/timothycrosley/isort#skip-processing-of-imports-outside-of-configuration

Comment: VSCode+isort here: this doesn't work

Comment: This also worked to stop isort from adding parenthesis around my comma-separated list of symbols when importing. i.e. it was turning `from a import x, y, z` into `from a import (x, y, z)` which was borking something. `from a import x, y, z # isort:skip` stopped it.

Comment: FYI, I'm on Windows 10 using vscode 1.66.1 and use `editor.codeActionsOnSave`.

Answer (score 7):

VS Code runs *autopep8* at save time and you can add the `# noqa` or `# nopep8` comment at the end of a line to exclude that line from checking/sorting:

```
sys.modules['module_A'] = Mock()

from module_to_test import function_to_test # noqa
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you should worry about sorting imports. Mock should take care of it, your tests should use context managers or decorators provided by `mock` module instead of directly assigning a `Mock` object yourself.

Take a look at '[patch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.patch)'.

Also look at '[where to patch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#where-to-patch)'

Comment: Thanks for the input. I was going off [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8658332/4049396), which seems to be a way of mocking that has worked for me until now. This question is more about how to stop the sort from happening. That said, I don't really understand how to apply a patch to pytest so I haven't tried it.

Comment: See https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference.html#monkeypatch on how to mock in pytest.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is coming from the autopep8 rules being run at save time. Specifically, rule E402, which requires all imports first.

Although I could not get VS Code or any of its packages to run a on the subset of files, I did find a solution to exclude a subset of autopep8 rules. Here is what the `settings.json` entry looks like,

```
    "python.formatting.provider": "autopep8",
    "python.formatting.autopep8Args": [
        "--ignore",
        "E402"
    ],
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54016555/4049396) for more information.