# Prevent VSCode from reorganizing a specific list of imports

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I currently have a python file that looks like this:

```py
import os
import sys

PROJECT_FOLDER = os.path.realpath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), ".."))
os.chdir(PROJECT_FOLDER)
sys.path.insert(0, PROJECT_FOLDER)
from settings import datagenerator as settings
```

Due to the way the settings and modules are organised in the project, I need to set some common working directory before importing the various files.

Since I am quite *lazy*, I like to use the 'Organize imports' in VScode. Unfortunately, it moves the line `from settings import datagenerator as settings`on top of the block setting the current path.

Even though it is to be expected. I was wonderings if there was a way to tell VSCode to keep those lines together.

Answer (score 0):

The extension uses [isort](https://pypi.org/project/isort/) to manage import resorting. So if isort provides a mechanism for marking an import as something to not move then the extension will also support it. Otherwise I'm afraid there isn't anything that can be done.

Answer (score 0):

As in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62705573/5176549) answer, explained, you can avoid sorting like this:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
from . import views  # isort:skip
i.e. Add the # isort:skip comment to the import you don't want to jump to the top of the file.
```

Source: https://github.com/timothycrosley/isort#skip-processing-of-imports-outside-of-configuration