# Python VSCode "moves" import

Tags: python, flask, formatting, visual-studio-code

Hello I'm trying to import routes to **init**.py and I'm keep getting circular import error because probably formatter moves up my import statement and I'm wondering what can I do with it my code should look like this

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
from .config import Config
app.config.from_object(Config)
from app import routes
```

But because of this "bug" I'm getting this

```
from app import routes
from .config import Config
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

app.config.from_object(Config)
```

When I removed formatter code stays good but I want to have formatter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried `autopep8`, `black` and `yapf`, only `autopep8` has this problem.

I have checked the [official docs](https://pypi.org/project/autopep8/) of `autopep8`, but I can't find any configuration that can disable it.

So, switch to `black` or `yapf`?

Comment: I think yapf would be the best

Comment: Having this in the settings prevents imports move:
"python.formatting.autopep8Args": ["--ignore","E402"]

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54015604/disable-python-import-sorting-in-vscode